# Background size cover not working on longer pages on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

This is a Next.js project and the mobile being used here is google pixel 3a. I'm having a problem where on longer pages my background image will not display at all. Here is how it looks on pages where the height is not exceeding the viewport height
[image]

But on some longer pages where you need to scroll to reach the bottom, it doesn't display at all

[image]

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/500");
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 5vw;
  padding-right: 5vw;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 90vw;
  font-family: system-ui;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}
```

If I change background-size to auto then it will work on every page, but I would like cover. Maybe I don't understand how cover works for pages where scrolling is required, but I would like the background image displayed as it is in the first image, and if the content is longer than the view port, the content should just scroll across the image without the image moving. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You might add some HTML content to the snippet I created to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, you want the background image to at least fill the viewport but if the body is higher than that you want it to fill the whole body.

Therefore, tell it that the min-height of the body must be 100vh and don't set an actual height, let it work it out from the content.

I'm assuming in this snippet that you want just one copy of the background, centered and using size cover (so it may get cropped top/bottom or at the sides depending on relative aspect ratios).

A dummy div is put in the snippet to ensure we get scrolling.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/500");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 5vw;
  padding-right: 5vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 90vw;
  font-family: system-ui;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

div {
  height: 350vh;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I copied your code and now the background image is working properly. I see that the crucial line in your code that is allowing it to work is 
```background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;```. If I comment that out it doesn't work anymore. Any idea on why that might be?